# I created a date checker but when I run it it displays wrong info

Tags: date, batch-file, time

So I got a code that checks for the weekday and then uses it to do other things. But there's a problem that (lets say today is Monday) when I run the code on my pc it says Mo (correct), but when I run it on my laptop it says 20 (not correct), can somebody help? This is the code :

```
@echo off
set day=%date:~0,2%
echo %day%
pause
```

Comment: Your code is using the `%DATE%` variable, which is dynamically created using the locale/user/PC settings. There are hundreds of examples on this site showing how to create a date independently of User, PC, or locale settings, please use the search facility, choose one, adapt it to your situation, and replace the code you're currently using.

Comment: Oh ok I understand but I actually forgot to mention that I need only the weekday not the whole date.

Answer (score 0):

The best and the correct method to get this is to use the date independently of the region `day/month` order, you can use `"WMIC os GET LocalDateTime /Value"` and `WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime GET DayOfWeek /value` as a source, since it's in ISO order:

---

```bat
@echo off & setlocal
Title Get the date and time independently of the region using WMIC
@for /f %%i in (
'WMIC OS GET LocalDateTime /value ^& WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime GET DayOfWeek /value'
) do (
    @for /f %%j in ("%%i") do set "%%j" & echo "%%j"
)

Set /a "tok=DayOfWeek+1"
@for /f "tokens=%tok%" %%i in (
"Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday"
) do (
    Set "Day=%%i"
    Set "D=%LocalDateTime:~6,2%"
    Set "M=%LocalDateTime:~4,2%"
    Set "yyyy=%LocalDateTime:~0,4%"
    Set "hh=%LocalDateTime:~8,2%"
    Set "mm=%LocalDateTime:~10,2%"
    Set "ss=%LocalDateTime:~12,2%"
)
echo( Created: %Day% the %D%/%M%/%yyyy% at %hh%:%mm%:%ss%
pause
```